# Ajax call and countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, countdowntimer

I have an AJAX call like the following and I want to have a countdown timer (nothing really visual, just a counter) with which it counts from a number down to zero and then starts the AJAX and **wait** till the AJAX is done and then count down again and ... forever.

So it goes like this:

```
  *    ---------    5 4 3 2 1 0    *    ---------    5 4 3 2 1
  |         |            |         |         |           |
ajax      wait         count      ajax      wait       count
```

Is it possible to do this with JavaScript and jQuery? I'm not looking for any plugin.

```
var request = $.ajax({
            url: "/rhino",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json"
        });

        request.done(function (data) {
            console.log("success");;
        });

        request.error(function (data) {
            console.log("failed");
        });
```

Comment: I would have the call in a web method and the timer in a windows service.  everytime the timer elapses the service consumes the web method.

Comment: @Dura, I'm actually looking for a client side solution. That's why I mentioned JS and jQuery. But thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work fine. Start an initial timeout, then set a timeout whenever you get a response.

```
var requeue = function() {
  setTimeout(performRequest, 1000);
};

var performRequest = function() {
  var request = $.ajax({
      url: "/rhino",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json"
  });

  request.done(function (data) {
      console.log("success", data);
      requeue();
  });

  request.error(function (data) {
      console.log("failed");
      requeue();
  });
};

requeue();
```

**[working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eAWZmfBl0STniM92LLuS?p=preview)**

Comment: Wouldn't that work only if the webpage was running? I thought the question was about automatising the call.